# Запятая в сложном предложении, объяснение запятой

Tags: запятые

К счастью, потомство одуванчика оказывается совсем не таким многочисленным, как ожидалось, и(,) если и произойдет когда-нибудь чудо(,) и потомство этого удивительного цветка окрепнет, (то) все равно не покрыть ему всей поверхности нашей планеты.

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему после "и" перед первым придаточным стоит запятая, ведь в главной части идет вторая часть двойного союза если...то? Почему второе придаточное отделяется запятой, соединенное с первым союзом и?

Answer (score 2):

**К счастью, потомство одуванчика оказывается совсем не таким многочисленным, как ожидалось, и если и произойдет когда-нибудь чудо и потомство этого удивительного цветка окрепнет, то все равно не покрыть ему всей поверхности нашей планеты.**

Второй блок сложного предложения: ...и (1) если и произойдет когда-нибудь чудо и (2) (если) потомство этого удивительного цветка окрепнет, (3) то все равно не покрыть ему всей поверхности нашей планеты.

Предложения 1 и 2 ― о**днородные условные придаточные** по отношению к главному предложению 3.

Запятая между 1 и 2 не ставится **при наличии одиночного союза И.** Запятая после союза И перед ЕСЛИ не ставится, так как это **двойной союз ЕСЛИ...ТО**.